# Do all the numbers have equal probability to be returned on every Random.Next() call?

Tags: c#, .net, random, probability

Is the probability of `Random.Next()` to return `x` the next time it's called lower than its probability of returning `y` if it has just returned `x`?

Comment: please refrain from betting big on the roulette table

Comment: I can't tell if this is a troll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if for example the number 5 is returned from your random call, the probability that 5 is chosen again is the same as any number within your range.

It helps somewhat to understand that [random distribution is different from regular distribution](http://cas.bellarmine.edu/tietjen/RootWeb/Measuring%20Spatial%20Distribution.htm).  Random distribution tends to create clusters of similar data, and is often not as regular as you might expect.

Comment: This would be true if `Random` was a random process which it is not.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to generate i.i.d. numbers, which stands for *independent*, identically distributed.

*Independent* means that the next number doesn't depend on the history in any way.

Of course, since it's a PRNG and not truly random, they won't be perfectly independent, but I doubt you can tell the difference.

Comment: prng is not at all random in the mathematical sense

Comment: @David: The internal state transition are not at all random.  Observable output transitions have some uncertainty (which decreases as you observe more terms in the sequence).

Answer (score 1):

`Random.Next` doesn't generate random numbers. It's next sample is known deterministically from its state.

For a true random number generator, that was producing iid samples, then there previous value would of course have no bearing on the next value. That's the independent part of iid.

Comment: Yet many states may give the same value of `Random.Next` so it makes sense to talk about the probability of obtaining something on subsequent calls to `Next`

Comment: @obrok I don't see where probability comes into a PRNG.

Comment: If all that is known is that `Random.Next` gave us 3 then knowing the underlying generator but not knowing the actual state of the generator we can calculate the probability of getting this or that on the next call to `Next`. Of course if we know the state we know the value `Random.Next` will give us with certainty.

Comment: @obrok You can only calculate that prob by making some distributional assumptions about how you came to be in the current state, which I guess would be possible. None of this is what has been asked I fear.

Comment: @David: The question explicitly asks about the conditional probability `P(X_t+1 = x | X_t = x)`

Comment: @Ben What's your distributional assumption that can make that a calculable value?

Comment: @David: If `x` is the trailing N bits of an M bit state variable, then I guess it would be the fraction of the 2**(M-N) possible states that return `x` for the next output as well.  Of course, brute forcing is quite expensive, but it might well be feasible to backsolve the state update equations, as there isn't any cryptographic hash involved.